# How can i run node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github

I'm using hapi-ninja, all is ok, and I would just run node server, but if I get these errors, I can not run it going to the route localhost:3000(Custom)

```
vagrant:/vagrant/hapi-ninja$ node server

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'boom'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/hapi-ninja/node_modules/hapi/lib/index.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
vagrant:/vagrant/hapi-ninja$
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all: you need the module `boom`.

To install, type in a terminal

```
npm install boom
```